# How can I refactor my code for this coding challenge?

Tags: javascript, arrays, database, object

I have finally complete the cash register challenge found on freecodecamp.org and I was wondering how I can further clean my code. I need help refactoring my code. Link to challenge here: https://learn.freecodecamp.org/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures-projects/cash-register

I feel my code is clean enough but I'm still new to coding

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  let result = {status: 'OPEN', change: []}

  const denomination = new Map([
    ['ONE HUNDRED', 100],   ['TWENTY', 20], 
    ['TEN', 10],            ['FIVE', 5],            
    ['ONE', 1],             ['QUARTER', 0.25],      
    ['DIME', 0.10],         ['NICKEL', 0.05],       
    ['PENNY', 0.01]]);

  let moneyDue = cash - price
  let total = cid.reduce((acc, next) => { 
     return acc + Math.round(next[1] * 100) / 100
  }, 0)

  if(total < moneyDue){  
    result.status = "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS"
    return result
  }
  else if(total === moneyDue){ 
    result.status = "CLOSED"
    result.change = cid
    return result
  }

  const newCID = new Map(cid.reverse())
  let count = -1
  let sum = 0

  for (let [denom, value] of denomination){
    count++
    while (value <= moneyDue && cid[count][1] > 0 ) {
      cid[count][1] -= value
      sum += value
      moneyDue -= value
      moneyDue = Math.round(moneyDue * 100) / 100
    }

    if (sum > 0){
    result.change.push([cid[count][0],sum]);}
    sum = 0;
  }

  if(moneyDue !== 0){
    result.status = "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS"
    result.change = []
    return result
  }
  return result;
}

checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.1], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90], ["FIVE", 55], ["TEN", 20], ["TWENTY", 60], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]])
```

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ might be a better place for this.

Comment: thx I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used some object destructuring, cleaned up the reduce function, updated the formatting and removed cleaned up some return functions. Hope this helps.

```
const checkCashRegister = (price, cash, cid) => {
  let result = { status: "OPEN", change: [] };

  const denomination = new Map([
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 100],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TEN", 10],
    ["FIVE", 5],
    ["ONE", 1],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["DIME", 0.1],
    ["NICKEL", 0.05],
    ["PENNY", 0.01]
  ]);

  let moneyDue = cash - price;
  const total = cid.reduce(
    (acc, next) => acc + Math.round(next[1] * 100) / 100,
    0
  );

  if (total < moneyDue) {
    return { change: result.change, status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS" };
  }
  if (total === moneyDue) {
    return { status: "CLOSED", change: cid };
  }

  const newCID = new Map(cid.reverse());
  let count = -1;
  let sum = 0;

  for (let [denom, value] of denomination) {
    count++;
    while (value <= moneyDue && cid[count][1] > 0) {
      cid[count][1] -= value;
      sum += value;
      moneyDue -= value;
      moneyDue = Math.round(moneyDue * 100) / 100;
    }

    if (sum > 0) {
      result.change.push([cid[count][0], sum]);
    }
    sum = 0;
  }

  if (moneyDue !== 0) {
    result = { status: "INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS", change: [] };
  }

  return result;
};

checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [
  ["PENNY", 1.01],
  ["NICKEL", 2.05],
  ["DIME", 3.1],
  ["QUARTER", 4.25],
  ["ONE", 90],
  ["FIVE", 55],
  ["TEN", 20],
  ["TWENTY", 60],
  ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]
]);
```

Comment: I have updated the answer. For some reason, the compiler was not taking the spread operator in the site. If you run the code in the browser with the spread operator it works. I also have removed the elseif condition from the code. Makes it cleaner.

Comment: You might want to look into spread operators too. It makes your code a lot cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** Here is my garbage code and I think no one's would be complicated than mine. Hope 
some one to help me clean it too. Thank you very much.**/


 function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
    
      cid = cid.reverse();
    
      cid[0][2]=100;
      cid[1][2]=20;
      cid[2][2]=10;
      cid[3][2]=5;
      cid[4][2]=1;
      cid[5][2]=0.25;
      cid[6][2]=0.1;
      cid[7][2]=0.05;
      cid[8][2]=0.01;
    
      let cha={};
      let total = cid.reduce((a,b)=>a+b[1],0);
      let charge = cash - price;
      let rc = charge;
      let arr = [];
    
      if (charge>total){
        cha.status="INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS";
        cha.change = [];
      }
    
      else{
      
      for (let item of cid){
        if (charge == 0){
          if (rc==total){
                arr.push(item);
            }
            break;
        }
        else{
          if (charge < item[2]){
            if (rc==total){
                arr.push(item);
          }
          continue;
        }
          else {
            let i=0;
            let v = item[1];
            while(charge>=item[2]&&v>0){
              
              v = v - item[2];
              charge = (charge - item[2]).toFixed(2);
              i++;  
              console.log(charge);  
                 
          }
          
          item[1]=i*item[2];
         }
       }    
        arr.push(item);
        
    }
    
       
       for (let item of arr){
         item.pop()
       }
       
        if (rc==total){
        cha.status="CLOSED";
        cha.change = arr.reverse();
      }
        else {
        cha.status="OPEN";
        cha.change = arr;
      }
      if (charge>0){
        cha.status="INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS";
        cha.change = [];
      }
        
      }
      
      return cha;
    
    }
    
    checkCashRegister(19.5, 20, [["PENNY", 0.5], ["NICKEL", 0], ["DIME", 0], ["QUARTER", 0], ["ONE", 0], ["FIVE", 0], ["TEN", 0], ["TWENTY", 0], ["ONE HUNDRED", 0]]);
```